# Filter a dropdown table combobox in a form (access 2013)

Tags: ms-access, filter

I have a table ProjectMilestone which is a list of multiple projects using multiple ProjectIDs with a column PredecessorMilestone which has a combo box which holds a list of the ProjectMilestoneID primary key column data of the same table.

In a form Projects_v18 I have a subform of the table ProjectMilestone that shows this same table data, albeit using a specific ProjectID to show a specific set of data. What I would like to do is filter the column PredecessorMilestone in the subform so that it would when clicked to see the dropdown list in a specific way that the dropdown list filters only a list of ProjectMilestoneIDs that are from a specific ProjectID in a field from the Projects_v18 form.

What is the process to apply this? I have tried for an on click event in the subform as the following:

```
Filter = "SELECT [ProjectMilestone].[ProjectMilestoneID], [Milestone].[MilestoneName], [Project].[ProjectName] FROM (ProjectMilestone INNER JOIN Milestone ON ProjectMilestone.MilestoneID = Milestone.MilestoneID) INNER JOIN Project ON ProjectMilestone.ProjectID = Project.ProjectID WHERE Project.ProjectID = '" & Forms!Project_v18!ProjectIDHidden.Text & "' ORDER BY [ProjectMilestoneID]"
Me.PredecessorMilestone.RowSource = Filter
```

However when I click on the dropdown list it is not filtering.

Comment: Have you verified that the code in the click event is actually running?

Comment: I tried to get the code to do a msgbox and it didn't work so it seems it is not running?
What do I need to do to get it to run?

Comment: Ok I got it to work once I selected something from the dropdown list. I'm trying to get it to work before the dropdown list is selected.

Comment: Use combobox GotFocus event. If this is VBA (not VB.net), don't use .Text property. Value is property should reference or don't bother because it is the default.

Comment: That worked once I used gotfocus and value. Thanks!

Comment: If ProjectID is a number type, don't use apostrophe delimiters. Never mind now if it is working.